# Why libcurl with SSL produces undefined reference errors on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, libcurl

I have been trying to set up libcurl for quite a while. The pre-built binaries available on the official website were not working for me (I was stuck with some strange LTO wrapper errors; most probably originated from compiler version mismatch). So I had to build both OpenSSL and libcurl from the scratch. When I'm building it without SSL, it runs perfectly without any hiccups (of course, neither cURL CLI nor libcurl lets me use https). But it functions properly with http on this [example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html).

Then I built libcurl with SSL. But when I try to test it on the same example, I'm getting all sorts of undefined reference errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in TestCurl (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(bio_ssl.o):bio_ssl.c|| undefined reference to `BIO_s_connect'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(bio_ssl.o):bio_ssl.c|| undefined reference to `BIO_s_connect'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl3_record.o):ssl3_record.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_expand_block'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl3_record.o):ssl3_record.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_compress_block'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl3_record.o):ssl3_record.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_expand_block'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl3_record.o):ssl3_record.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_expand_block'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_get_type'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_get_name'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c|| undefined reference to `EVP_enc_null'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_get_type'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_ciph.o):ssl_ciph.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_get_name'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| more undefined references to `COMP_CTX_free' follow|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `OCSP_SINGLERESP_get1_ext_d2i'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_new'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set1_cert'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set1_issuer'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set_shared_CTLOG_STORE'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_set_time'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `CT_POLICY_EVAL_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_get_method'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_get_method'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `X509_STORE_set_default_paths'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c|| undefined reference to `X509_STORE_load_locations'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(t1_lib.o):t1_lib.c|| undefined reference to `BN_get_rfc3526_prime_3072'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(t1_lib.o):t1_lib.c|| undefined reference to `BN_get_rfc3526_prime_8192'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Calc_B'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_get_default_gN'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_create_verifier_BN'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Verify_A_mod_N'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Calc_u'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Calc_server_key'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Verify_B_mod_N'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Calc_u'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Calc_x'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Calc_client_key'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_check_known_gN_param'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(tls_srp.o):tls_srp.c|| undefined reference to `SRP_Calc_A'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(s3_enc.o):s3_enc.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_free'|
dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a(s3_enc.o):s3_enc.c|| undefined reference to `COMP_CTX_new'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Following are the details of my system:

- **Compiler**: g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
- **libcurl**: 7.68.0
- **OpenSSL**: 1.1.1d
- **OS**: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362

These are the commands that the IDE (Code::Blocks) is issuing:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -lssl -lcrypto -DCURL_STATICLIB -g -Idependencies\CURL\include -c G:\App\TestCurlCB\src\Manager.cpp -o obj\Debug\src\Manager.o

mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\TestCurl.exe obj\Debug\src\Manager.o   dependencies\CURL\lib\libcurl.a dependencies\SSL\lib\libcrypto.a dependencies\SSL\lib\libssl.a "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\Wldap32.Lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\WS2_32.Lib"
```

Comment: I think `libcrypto.a` should be after `libssl.a` in the second command.

Comment: @ssbssa Thanks, that certainly was the issue :)(although, technically I figured it out myself soon after posting the question). Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks for the help anyway.